# dbTest not defined

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Am going through my spark training on databricks but everthing seems to be breaking down when I click run. I have this error

error: name 'dbTest' is not defined

when I run this below:

```
ip1, count1 = ipCountDF.first()
cols = set(ipCountDF.columns)
dbTest("ET1-P-02-01-01", "213.152.28.bhe", ip1) 
dbTest("ET1-P-02-01-02", True, count1 > 500000 and count1 < 550000)
dbTest("ET1-P-02-01-03", True, 'count' in cols)
dbTest("ET1-P-02-01-03", True, 'ip' in cols)

print("Tests passed!")
```

please guys any tips?